# substring extraction

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a string in the below format:

```
00:aa:bb:cc:dd:ee
```

I need to split it and output only first 3 fields, i.e. 00:aa:bb. I am using

```
s.split(':')[1:3]
```

in my program to do the job, but its not helping. Is it the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean it's not helping? Is it because the result is a list? To turn it back to a string try:

```
':'.join(s.split(':')[0:3])
```

Also note the zero-index.

Answer (score 5):

Almost: Python is 0-indexed (counts from 0):

```
>>> s = '00:aa:bb:cc:dd:ee'
>>> s.split(":")
['00', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee']
>>> s.split(":")[0:3]
['00', 'aa', 'bb']
>>> s.split(":")[:3]
['00', 'aa', 'bb']
```

And you could recombine them:

```
>>> ':'.join(s.split(":")[:3])
'00:aa:bb'
```

You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation) for a brief review of how Python slicing works, if that's the issue.

Comment: Since he only needs the first 3, splitting the rest is a waste.  Could just do `':'.join(s.split(':', 3)[:3])` so the interpreter will drop out of the parse after getting the tokens he needs and no more.

Comment: @sr2222: yep, you're right.  `timeit` difference: 1090 ns vs 931 ns.  I don't think I'll worry too much. :^)

Comment: Depends how many strings he has, but true.  :)  Also, if all the strings look just like the one shown (2 char sequences delimited by colons), just doing `s[:8]` would be even better.